# Problem with boost 'undefined reference to'

Tags: compiling, c++, boost

I'm trying to set up [this program (vocus2)](http://pages.iai.uni-bonn.de/frintrop_simone/vocus2.html)

I have install both boost and opencv after cmake . i get a confirmation

> -- Boost version: 1.46.1
>
> -- Found the following Boost libraries:
>
> --   serialization

But after i make i get the error

```
CMakeFiles/vocus2.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `boost::archive::xml_iarchive::xml_iarchive(std::istream&, unsigned int)':
/usr/local/boost_1_46_1/boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp:149: undefined reference to `boost::archive::detail::shared_ptr_helper::shared_ptr_helper()'
CMakeFiles/vocus2.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `boost::archive::xml_iarchive::~xml_iarchive()':
/usr/local/boost_1_46_1/boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp:151: undefined reference to `boost::archive::detail::shared_ptr_helper::~shared_ptr_helper()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/vocus2.dir/build.make:140: recipe for target 'vocus2' failed
make[2]: *** [vocus2] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/vocus2.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/vocus2.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```